# PostgREST filter returns incorrect results when value contains a space

Tags: postgresql-9.4, postgrest

Using current version of PostgREST (v.0.3.2.0), attempting a very simple GET call:

Db contains two records with the following accountNames: "Account 1" and "Account #2".

This works:

```
GET localhost:3000/accounts?accountName=eq.Account 1
```

==> proper data is retrieved.

This does NOT work:

```
GET localhost:3000/accounts?accountName=eq.Account #2
```

==> NO data is retrieved.  Obviously the # character prevents the filter from working properly.

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/accounts?accountName=eq.Account%20%232.`  Use Urlencoding.

Comment: Not getting this.  Without knowing what the value of the accountName string will be at data entry time, how does one know how to format it in the url?  This answer will not work.

Comment: it's called url encoding ... encodeURIComponent(value);

Comment: That's it!  Please edit your answer so that I can upvote it.